# Formula for standard deviation

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

So I am studying for a final exam and I know, or thought I knew, the formula for standard deviation. I quadruple checked in my notes and the slides for the lecture and see that the formula for the standard deviation when $\sigma$ is unknown is:

$\sqrt((\Sigma d^2 - nd^-) /  n - 1)$

But for some reason on the final review solution sheet our professor somehow and some reason replaced $n$ in the numerator with $1/n$ and I have no clue why. So the formula is now:

$\sqrt((\Sigma d^2 - (1/n)d^-) / n - 1)$

My question is, how come we are able to use $1/n$ instead of $n$ and on the test, how can I tell to use $1/n$ as compared to $n$?

Thanks

Comment: What is $d$ in this formula?

Comment: The mean of the sample differences.

Comment: You mean just the differences? And $\bar d$ is the mean of the differences?

Comment: Yes! That is correct!

Comment: One more question, so is $d_i=x_i-\mu$.  So the deviation from the mean?

Comment: $x_i - \mu$? You mean $x_i - y_i$?

Comment: Ok! That's the distinction I wanted.  So this is the standard deviation for **paired samples**? Which is different than the standard deviation for independent sample in general.

Comment: Yes it is. Is the $1/n$ only used for paired samples?

Comment: I am still trying to figure out why the standard deviation is what it is, but at least I understand the problem more clearly now.

Comment: I think my professor is wrong here. Literally every time the standard deviation formula appears in the notes and examples she did in class its just $n$. The other way, $1/n$ literally never appears. I wonder if its a typo.

Comment: Give me two minutes and I'll explain why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes your professor has a typo.  The standard deviation for paired samples is usually written as follows:

$$\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(d_i-\bar d)^2}{n-1}}$$

What you professor is doing is using the trick (or arithmetic if you want to think of it that way) that we can rewrite the numerator as

$$\sum_{i=1}^n(d_i-\bar d)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^nd_i^2-n\bar d^2$$

And thus, the formula for the standard deviation should be

$$\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(d_i-\bar d)^2}{n-1}}= \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(d_i)^2-n\bar d^2}{n-1}}$$

And finally, it should be $n$ and not $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Okay, awesome. Thank you so much. I was working a bunch of these problems and was starting to freak out that I kept getting the wrong answers. I saw in her solutions that she was using $1/n$ and thought that couldn't be right. Glad to know I was on the right track. Thank you for clearing up the confusion I had.

Comment: @GenericUser01 No problem.  Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Sample variance is defined as
\begin{align}
&\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(d_i-\overline{d}\right)^2}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(d_i^2+\overline{d}^2-2d_i\overline{d}\right)} \\
&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\left[\sum_{i=1}^nd_i^2+\sum_{i=1}^n\overline{d}^2-\sum_{i=1}^n2d_i\overline{d}\right]}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\left[\sum_{i=1}^nd_i^2+n\overline{d}^2-2\overline{d}\sum_{i=1}^nd_i\right]}\\
&\overset{(a)}{=}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\left[\sum_{i=1}^nd_i^2+n\overline{d}^2-2n\overline{d}^2\right]}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\left[\sum_{i=1}^nd_i^2-n\overline{d}^2\right]}\\
\end{align}
$(a)$ follows since sample mean $\overline{d}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nd_i$.
Hence it is $n\overline{d}$ not $(1/n) \overline{d}$

Comment: There's a typo in your second line with an extra 2 term in the power.

Comment: You are right, actually I saw your solution after publishing, you have solved it already, mine is just elaborated form. I will make change. Thank you.